# CI: form validation then inserting data securely (but without characters converted to html code)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, encoding, character-encoding

I'm processing a registration form and this is how I do it currently:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name','First Name','trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name','Last Name', 'trim|required');
....

if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE)
{                                               
    $data = array('first_name' => set_value('first_name')
    ....


// model
$this->db->insert('registration',$data))
```

**Problem:**

If the name has an apostrophe in it, it ends up in MySQL as `&#39;`

What would be the best way to process and input this data into MySQL securely but without encoding these types of characters?

Comment: do you have global XSS filtering on?

Comment: Use mysql_real_escape_string or this->db->escape();